# Python - Deleting a single row in a csv

Tags: python, csv

I'd like to filter a csv based on this list:

```
items = ["1", "test", "11", "9", "2003"]
```

after that it should remove the entry in the csv file that has the exact same values as the list.

My code looks like this:

```
import csv

items = ["1", "test", "11", "9", "2003"]
Id, name, day, month, year = items
with open("database.csv",  newline="") as reader:
    db_readrow = csv.reader(reader, delimiter=";")
    for x in db_readrow:
        with open("database.csv", "w", newline="") as deleter, open("database.csv", "a", newline="") as writer:
            db_deleterow = csv.writer(deleter, delimiter=";")
            db_addrow = csv.writer(writer, delimiter=";")
            if x[0] == "Id":
                db_deleterow.writerow(["Id", "name", "day", "month", "year"])

            elif Id != x[0] and name != x[1] and day != x[2] and month != x[3] and year != x[4]:
                db_addrow.writerow([x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]])
```

Before I run this, csv looks like this:

[image: before]

After I run it, this occurs:

[image: After]

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having multiple writers to the same file operating at the same time is unlikely to work.

Instead, create a second file and write to that all the records except the one you are filtering out. You can delete the original and rename the new file to the original name to achieve the same as writing in place, if that's what you need.